# jQuery Background Canvas transparency

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, jquery-plugins, transparency

I'm using the [jQuery Background Canvas](http://www.maierhofer.de/en/open-source/jquery-background-canvas-plugin.aspx) plugin and have created a DIV with rounded corners and a gradient effect. However, I'm unable to get the transparency to work. What am I doing wrong? Here's the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".Test").backgroundCanvas();
$(".Test").makeElementTransparent("#CECFCE");
$(".Test").backgroundCanvas(true, "#CECFCE");
});

function DrawBackground() {
$(".Test").backgroundCanvasPaint(TestBackgroundPaintFkt);
}
// Draw the background on load and resize
$(window).load(function () { DrawBackground(); });
$(window).resize(function() { DrawBackground(); });

function TestBackgroundPaintFkt(context, width, height, elementInfo)
{
var options = {x:0, height: height, width: width,
radius:7, border: 0 };
// Draw the red border rectangle
context.fillStyle = "#CECFC6";
$.canvasPaint.roundedRect(context,options);
// Draw the gradient filled inner rectangle
var backgroundGradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0,
0, height - 10);
backgroundGradient.addColorStop(0 ,'#F7F7EF');
backgroundGradient.addColorStop(1, '#CECFCE');
options.border = 1;
context.fillStyle = backgroundGradient;
$.canvasPaint.roundedRect(context,options);
}
```

The element itself looks like this:

```
<div class="Test">
   something here
</div>
```

And here's the CSS for it:

```
.Test {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: I think I might have mistaken the transparent functionality of this library with the alpha transparency you can apply to elements in HTML. In fact, it's the alpha transparency that I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.
In my case, the following line did the trick:

```
$('#*[canvasId]*').css('background-color','transparent');
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution has nothing to do with this jQuery library; it's the opacity/transparency CSS attributes. For Firefox and Safari, this does the trick:

```
.Test {
   -moz-opacity:0.5; /* For older FF versions */
   -khtml-opacity:0.5;
   opacity:0.5;
}
```

For IE, this was necessary:

```
canvas.jbgCanvas {
   filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

In most cases, you should be able to apply the filter attribute to your element; but in this case, the only way it worked was to apply it to the CANVAS object.