# HTML5 Multiple Layers, can't see lower layers

Tags: html, html5-canvas, layer

I'm trying to impliment a simple game with multiple canvas layers. The problem is I can only see the "top" layer.

http://carmenbranje.com/games/untangle%20game%203/

Why is this?

Thanks very much

Carmen

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed it!
But you seem to have no z-indexing on your canvas.
This will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added z-index to the canvas elements in untangle.css. Still only the "ui" canvas is visible. If I delete <canvas id="ui" width="768" height="440"></canvas> from index.html =, I can see the layer directly below, but not the one below that.

Comment: But you have only set the z-index to zero.
You need to set them all in order in which you need them to appear on the page.

You need to do it via the id of each canvas.

Comment: #bg{
z-index:0; 
}
#guide {
opacity: .7;
z-index:1;
}
#guide.fadeout {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
#game{
position:relative;
z-index:2;
}
#ui {
-webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear;
transition: opacity .3s linear;
z-index:3;

}
#ui.dim {
opacity: .3;
}

Comment: I have z-indexes for each canvas element in the .css file.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way. (There is a more tidy CSS way).
Try the below in your external CSS doc.

```
#layers canvas{
left: 50%;
margin-left: -384px;
position: absolute;
}

#bg{ z-index:1; }
#guide{ z-index:2; }
#game{ z-index:3; }
#ui{ z-index:4; }
```

Comment: Did this, I still can only see the top layer.

Comment: What browsers are you using to view this?

Answer (score 0):

This answer discusses background opacity for canvas: [jQuery Background Canvas transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389217/jquery-background-canvas-transparency)
Could that be what is missing?

Comment: If I put the ui canvas opacity to 0.5 I can see the layer underneath but it's faded . .

Comment: I would suggest then that opacity is the key, and you just need to devise a way to make all layers transparent  (opacity=0) in the background. You must be on the right track so will not bore you with more code. Play with what you have.